# python script slow after base64 module import

Tags: python

I am trying to generate keys using os.urandom() and base64 methods. Please see the below code. gen_keys() itself may not be very slow, but
the script overall run time is very slow. For example, gen_keys() takes
about 0.85 sec where as the overall script run time is is 2 minutes 6 seconds. I suspect this is some thing to do with module imports. Although I need all of the modules from my script.

Any thoughts on the real issue? Thanks.

I am using python3.4

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import netifaces
import os
import subprocess
import shlex
import requests
import time
import json
import psycopg2
import base64

def gen_keys():
    start_time = time.time()
    a_tok = os.urandom(40)
    a_key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(a_tok).rstrip(b'=').decode('ascii')
    s_tok = os.urandom(64)
    s_key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(s_tok).rstrip(b'=').decode('ascii')
    print("a_key: ", a_key)
    print("s_key: ", s_key)
    end_time = time.time()
    print("time taken: ", end_time-start_time)

def Main():
    gen_keys()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()

$~: time ./keys.py 
a_key:  52R_5u4I1aZENTsCl-fuuHU1P4v0l-urw-_5_jCL9ctPYXGz8oFnsQ
s_key:  HhJgnywrfgfplVjvtOciZAZ8E3IfeG64RCAMgW71Z8Tg112J11OHewgg0r4CWjK_SJRzYzfnN-igLJLRi1CkeA
time taken:  0.8523025512695312

real    2m6.536s
user    0m0.287s
sys 0m7.007s
$~:
```

Comment: It runs fast for me without netifaces and psycopg2, which I don't have installed. Since your minimal example doesn't use most of those imports, try removing the ones that aren't used and see if it's faster. If so you can do a manual binary search by adding them back until it's slow.

Comment: Or just interleave the imports with prints to see which one is slow.